# "—surprise—" meaning in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> At the press conference, Trump announced he planned to invest $250 million to build two "super-luxury" residential towers, to be called Trump International ***and—surprise—Trump*** Tower, both of which he said "Moscow desperately wants and needs. "

I figure "surprise" here means it's not a surprise it's called Trump Tower.  But I'm unsure if I get it right.  What does it truly mean here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call it sarcasm more than irony.  Trump likes to go around naming things "Trump Tower" so it is really NOT a surprise that he is doing it again.

Answer (score 3):

This is irony. To understand this you need to appreciate the full context.

As irony, it is a parenthetical comment (marked by dashes) that means  ".... (and this is not a surprise)..."

In a non-ironic way.  People will say "Surprise!" as an interjection when saying something surprising.

> Here is your coffee and — surprise!— I made waffles!

But it is also very commonly used ironically, sometimes duplicated, and means "This is not a surprise.  You need to consider the context to understand if it is ironic.  In this case you should be aware that Trump has set up a tower named "Trump Tower" [in many locations around the world](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-many-trump-towers-are-there-2019-1?r=US&IR=T#demand-for-apartments-at-trump-tower-punta-del-este-is-on-the-rise-10)